# initialize And Print a Array with while loop

Tags: java, arrays

My project question. I have to use a double while loop.

Write a method demoArray2 in which you:

1. Use a while loop to initialize each element in the array with the following value:
   200 + 2*i
   where i is the index you use in the while loop.
2. Use a second while loop to output the integers. See Figure 2.
   i can't seem to Initialize and print it.

code:

```
 public void demoArray2()
 {
     int [] intArray = new int[10];
     int index = 0;
     while (index < 10) 
     {
         intArray[index] = 200 + 2*index;
     }
     int index = 0;
     while( index < 10)
     {
          System.out.println("Element at index " + index + " is " + intArray[index]);
          index = index +1;
     }

 }
```

Any help would be much appricated

Comment: `i can't seem to Initialize and print it.` What's the problem?

Comment: you're not incrementing the index in the first while loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to increment the index in your first loop.
You're also declaring the same variable twice, instead, just reassign the variable to 0.
I'm not sure, but that space between the "int" and "[]" might also be a problem.
Try something like this:

```
public void demoArray2() {
    int[] intArray = new int[10];
    int index = 0;
    while (index < 10) {
        intArray[index] = 200 + 2*index;
        index++;
    }
    index = 0;
    while( index < 10) {
        System.out.println("Element at index " + index + " is " + intArray[index]);
        index = index +1;
    }
}
```

`index++;` is the same as `index=index+1;`

Comment: Thanks jake it worked perfect. exellent spot. I inputed the index= 0;

Comment: My brain is melted from looking java at this thing too long.

Answer (score 0):

You never do `index = index + 1` in the first while loop

Comment: Sorry that was a copy typo in loop 1

Comment: can you fix the typo then

Answer (score 0):

```
     int index = 0;
     while (index < 10) 
     {
         intArray[index] = 200 + 2*index;
     }
```

This is an infinite loop. You must increment `index`. In this case, a `for` loop is commonly used:

```
     for (int index = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
         intArray[index] = 200 + 2*index;
     }
```

Comment: problem is it is required to use a while loop to Intialize the intArray. and print also with a while loop

Comment: `it is required` how so?

Comment: it is probably a homework problem

Comment: We have used the for loop to answer the assignment, now we must use the while loop method.

Comment: then just put the `index++;` before the end of the loop.

Comment: Yes its like homework. Just its a contineous assignment

Answer (score 0):

You declare index twice, you never increment index in the first loop.